# How to change a link's text based on different phrasing of the link's title attribute?

Tags: javascript, jquery, greasemonkey, tampermonkey

In my Fantasy football page, it gives stats about the opposing team and when you mouseover it tells you how many points they give up (See picture).

Here is the relevant code pertaining to this:

```
<a class="Inline F-rank-good" title="WAS gives up the 3rd most fantasy points to the QB position." target="_blank" href="/f1/777400/pointsagainst?pos=QB&ntid=28">Was</a>
```

How do I create a Greasemonkey script that will add the # to the end of the team name (i.e. "Was" becomes "Was - 3"

One problem there is, is that sometimes the rank says it gives up the "2nd fewest points", in which case you would have to do 32-2 to get the absolute rank.

[image: link showing mouseover]

Comment: Do not add additional questions to one that was resolved as is.  Open a new question for new problems, even if they are loosely related. Edits are to ***clarify*** an existing question, not pose a new one.

Comment: Ok I asked a [new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26539230)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extract the number from the `title` attribute, using regex that switches based on the surrounding text.

The following, complete but untested, Greasemonkey script illustrates the process:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name     FF, stat delinker
// @include  http://YOUR_SERVER.COM/YOUR_PATH/*
// @require  http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js
// @require  https://gist.github.com/raw/2625891/waitForKeyElements.js
// @grant    GM_addStyle
// ==/UserScript==
/*- The @grant directive is needed to work around a design change
    introduced in GM 1.0.   It restores the sandbox.
*/
waitForKeyElements ("a.Inline", delinkChangeStat);

function delinkChangeStat (jNode) {
    var rawText     = jNode.attr ("title")  ||  "";
    var deltaText   = "";
    var mtchResult  = null;

    //-- IMPORTANT: the single =, in the if() statements, is deliberate.

    //-- Like "gives up the 3rd most"
    if (mtchResult  = rawText.match (/gives up the (\d+)[a-t]{2} most/i) ) {
        deltaText   = mtchResult[1]; 
    }
    //-- Like "gives up the 2nd fewest points"
    else if (mtchResult = rawText.match (/gives up the (\d+)[a-t]{2} fewest/i) ) {
        deltaText   = 32 - parseInt (mtchResult[1], 10); 
    }
    //-- ADD ADDITIONAL else if() CLAUSES HERE AS NEEDED.

    //-- Change the link
    if (deltaText) {
        jNode.text (jNode.text () + " - " + deltaText);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code looks solid but it does not seem to work. I added a `console.debug("test");` in the `delinkChangeStat()` function but i do not see it.

Comment: Link to the target page.

Comment: It works now! My problem was that I installed it as a Chrome extension but I had to install Tampermonkey extension :)

Comment: I had to make slight modification because if the team gives up the most or fewest, it would not say "Gives up the 1st most..". A simple else if statement fixed that :)

Comment: So I did a good job of anticipating problems that weren't in the question? ;)  Glad you got it working. Upvote please.

Comment: Yes it worked seamless. I will update in 2hrs. I've used all my votes for the day ;_;

Comment: I have added a follow question to my original post. Would you be able to assist? I want to change F-link-secondary to F-Rank-Good/Neutral/Bad depending on the value of deltaText.

Comment: open a new question for that.  Try to provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  jQuery's `addClass` and `removeClass` are what you want to look into.