# Add class in jQuery in Greasemonkey script

Tags: javascript, jquery, greasemonkey, tampermonkey

I [Asked a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26533871) earlier and was given a [Working solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26537760/2893712). One thing I want to do is incorporate jQuery to remove a class `F-link-secondary` and replace it with F-rank-good/bad/neutral depending on the value of deltaText.

On most pages this is what I see:

[image]

But on a certain page, the F-rank-XXX class is not there and instead there is just a single F-link-secondary which has no style.

[image]

Here is what I want to do but I am not sure how to incorporate it with the Greasemonkey script.

```
function getRank(deltaText) {
    if((1 <= deltaText) && (deltaText <= 10))
        $("???").removeClass("F-link-secondary").addClass("F-rank-good");
    if((11 <= deltaText) && (deltaText <= 22))
        $("???").removeClass("F-link-secondary").addClass("F-rank-neutral");
    if((23 <= deltaText) && (deltaText <= 32))
        $("???").removeClass("F-link-secondary").addClass("F-rank-bad");
}
```

Comment: I don't think this question will be useful to anyone else.  Try to rephrase it so that it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, just add the code inside the `delinkChangeStat` function.
From:

```
//-- Change the link
if (deltaText) {
    jNode.text (jNode.text () + " - " + deltaText);
}
```

To:

```
//-- Change the link
if (deltaText) {
    jNode.text (jNode.text () + " - " + deltaText);

    var deltaVal = parseInt (deltaText, 10);

    if ( (1 <= deltaVal)  &&  (deltaVal <= 10) )
        jNode.removeClass ("F-link-secondary").addClass ("F-rank-good");
    else if ( (11 <= deltaVal) && (deltaVal <= 22) )
        jNode.removeClass ("F-link-secondary").addClass ("F-rank-neutral");
    else if ( (23 <= deltaVal) && (deltaVal <= 32) )
        jNode.removeClass ("F-link-secondary").addClass ("F-rank-bad");
}
```